# Is it possible to undo, undone changes in visual studios git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, undo

so I accidentally right clicked a file in my visual studios and pressed undo. I think this :

- Discard uncommitted changes to a file, bringing the file back to the
  version in the last commit.
- Reset your local branch to a previous commit.
- Revert changes pushed to a remote branch and shared with others.

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/undo?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio

The question is, can I undo what I have undone? Is it possible to get the file back in which I pressed undo?

Comment: _If_ you have staged a changed, then git-recover may be able to help.  But if you did not stage your changes before you undid them, it will be difficult to recover. https://github.com/ethomson/git-recover

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me and after none of the reflectors returned code I can actually use I searched the entire PC for my file name and found backups in weird folders like:
C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\VSFeedbackIntelliCodeLogs\Suggestions\6e92db73-0026-48ae-937b-0a62d36478c9\output\versions

Fortunately I was able to find my deleted files.

Comment: Hi Avner Levi, you undid the edit proposed by a well-meaning fellow user (and approved by some experienced other users). You are of course well within your rights to do so. In this special case however, I find that the edit was actually improving your posts readability. So I invite you to explain your reasons and maybe consider future improving edits to your posts more openly.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution. It applies after a git-undo in Visual Studio, on files that are currently open for editing.

You can go to those files in Visual Studio and just do a Control-Z. It will revert the last action (the undo on the file), and you will get your changes back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky (like I was) you might have copied the code that was undone. Click on "Edit" on the toolbar at the top of the screen and then choose "Show clipboard history".

You might find some of your code there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go to your Visual Studio folder and check the Backup Files folder for the old version of your file. Other than that, if you might have made a backup copy or if your machine is part of a scheduled backup, you might find your file archived somewhere. Finally, you might be able to use a data-recovery product such as R/Studio to recover your file, although this probably won't work if you've replace a file with old contents by using Undo.

Undo only reverts changes to the file you select in Solution Explorer. It does not do anything with local branches and it does not push. The link you cite does not mention anything of the sort with respect to using Undo.

By the way, Undo presents an "Are you sure?" dialog box. You should not be able to accidentally click it and suffer consequences unless you confirm that it's really what you want to do.

This still is an answer to your question even if you cannot successfully Undo your Undo operation and get your file restored. If you agree, please accept as Answer even if you don't get your file back... :)

Edit: As Edward Thomson commented above, you may be able to recover using git-recover if you first staged your changes. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks Edward!